# Setup ICP 2.1.0 (IBM Cloud Private) fails due to ssh troubles. Single host installation under Ubuntu

Tags: ssh-keys, ibm-cloud-private

When running 
sudo docker run --net=host -t -e LICENSE=accept -v $(pwd):/installer/cluster    ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0-ee install

**I get fatal: [192.168.201.130] => Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).**

I have debugged the session: 
root@icpecm:/opt/ibm-cloud-private-2.1.0/cluster# ssh -vvv -i cluster/ssh_key root@192.168.201.130
this is successful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Have you copied the public key in all the nodes?

In your case:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.201.130
```